# Script to Create a Tar, Log and Zip file from a list of files

Tags: bash, macos, archive, php-ziparchive

I want to be able to run a command on Mac to take a list of files and to Tar and Create a log file each for each file in the list. Then take each Tar file and create its own Zip file so we can archive.

Does anyone have any scripts or ideas to help achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't ask someone to do an entire script for you. 
Basically you have to cycle, run a tar command and echo whatever you want to log in  a log file. It isn't a difficult script to make, but you should come up something rather than ask for the full script.

Comment: Sorry I have the 1st part of my Script tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt. But this just creates one archive file. I'd like it to create separate archive files.

Comment: I'd recommend to modity the post with the script you already have